# Mysql cascade when updating/deleting null field

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, nullable, cascade

I have a table with two fields, one nullable and one not-nullable. These fields constitute a composite unique key on this table

```
CREATE TABLE `sections` (
  `product_id` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `sections` 
   ADD UNIQUE KEY (`product_id`, `id`);
```

I have another table, with a foreign key constraint on the unique-key fields of first table

```
CREATE TABLE `sections_t` (
  `product_id` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `sections_t`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sections_t_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`, `section_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`product_id`, `id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Everything seems to work fine when I update/delete entries on `sections` table having `product_id` not null. But when I update/delete an entry having `product_id` null, the change is not cascaded to `sections_t`.

How can I cascade changes involving entries with null fields?

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL allows a FK (foreign key) referencing nullable columns. But although MySQL lets you do it with InnoDB [it doesn't implement it properly & it tells you not to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that reference only keys that are both UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) and NOT NULL.

But SQL really is not designed to support subrows with NULLs as identifiers:

Do you understand that FK matching in the default & usual & usually only implemented mode (including in MySQL) is that if any FK column is NULL then the FK constraint is considered satisfied, no matter what is in the referenced table? And that in no mode does a NULL FK column value match anything in the referenced table, including another NULL? So even if you use the MySQL feature you will never get a match to a FK of the form (x, NULL).

(Do you understand that in the spirit of SQL NULL <> NULL if a FK subrow with a NULL did have to have an equal in its referenced table then it never would, because nothing in the referenced table can equal that NULL anyway, even a NULL?)

Do you understand that in standard SQL a UNIQUE index definition without NULL allows any number of rows of the form (p, NULL) in a table? (It's only "unique" in the perverted SQL 3VL sort of way.) (SQL Server is slightly different.) So is that UNIQUE with a nullable column really capturing the constraint that you want in your *referenced* table?

Do you understand that querying will be complicated because if you manually want (x, NULL) pairs included with (x, non-NULL) pairs you have to write things like OR id IS NULL?

If you want those tables you will have to write triggers for constraints & cascading. But you should use a design that uses NULL the way SQL expects & supports. That will still likely also involve some triggers but you will likely be able to use some declarative constraining & cascading & your design won't be non-standard & counter-intuitive in terms of SQL usage.